# Did 10.0.2 break some forms for named slots?

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

Since 10.0.2 some code that previously worked using named slots fail in very particular circumstances.

Attchd screenshot shows the issue w/ a particular `Dataset` which involves multiple pre-processing steps to construct, so cannot display here.

Lookup using form `#name&` fails, while the more normal forms or in `Key` form work.

[image]

However, it's difficult to reproduce this issue in a minimal example. When I try to project out a few rows and columns from this table to copy-paste it as text, subsequent re-casting to `Dataset` works w/ all forms of `Slot`.

Can anyone reproduce?

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to reproduce this so far. I'd like to remark that you can drop the double quotes in the last slot form.

Comment: What's the ``Dataset`GetType`` of `byVisit`? My debugging process for these things would be to do `Normal[Query[All,#KinectSyncTime&]]` to get the compiled query, then do `compiledquery ** type` to see what the type inference thinks (it will yield a `FailureType` judging by the error you saw).

Answer (score 7):

Following discussion w/ Jason Grigsby at WRI, rather than edit the Q w/ additional detail, the conclusion is that composite `Keys` such as lists of strings, interfere with above-mentioned named slot access:

```
data = <|"a" -> 1, {"b", "c"} -> 2|> // Dataset;

data[#["a"] &]
```

> 1

while

```
data[#"a" &]
```

> ```
> Failure[Function, 
> Association[
>  "MessageTemplate" :> MessageName[Function, "slot1"], 
>   "MessageParameters" -> {"a", Slot["a"]& , 
> TypeSystem`SkeletonForm[
> TypeSystem`Assoc[TypeSystem`AnyType, 
> TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 2]]}]]
> ```

Comment: This is now fixed. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Can you confirm, that `#"boing"` is officially supported as alternative to `#["boing"]`? I ask because I need to review some things for named slots in the [IntelliJ plugin](http://mathematicaplugin.halirutan.de/) anyway and I would like to support it completely. The documentation for `Slot` doesn't even mention the `#"name"` form.

Comment: @halirutan if you look at FullForm[#"boing"] you'll see it is exactly the same as #boing -- they parse to the same thing. For some reason #"boing" is not documented. I've reported that as a bug.