# 10.0.2 another Dataset type system (inference?) warning

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2**

---

The warning below seems unrelated to these issues:  [Did 10.0.2 break some forms for named slots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/did-10-0-2-break-some-forms-for-named-slots/69098#69098) and [10.0.2 mapping Association to Dataset warning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68875/10-0-2-mapping-association-to-dataset-warning).

First noticed w/ `TimeObject` but that turns out a red herring:

```
data = List[Association[Rule["WEBCAM_TIME",TimeObject[List[0,12,27.9`]]],Rule["VisitStartTime",TimeObject[List[0,12,15.`]]]],Association[Rule["WEBCAM_TIME",TimeObject[List[0,12,28.`]]],Rule["VisitStartTime",TimeObject[List[0,12,15.`]]]]];

Dataset[data]
```

[image]

Below, named `Slot` lookup syntax makes no difference, eg `#[x]` versus `#x`, nor `<|...|>` versus `Association`:

```
Dataset[data][All, 
 Association[#, "time" -> #["WEBCAM_TIME"] - #["VisitStartTime"]] &]
```

> Keys::invrl: The argument
>   Keys[Association[Struct[{WEBCAM_TIME,Atom[String]},{Atom[TimeObject],Atom[TimeObject]}],time->-Struct[{WEBCAM_TIME,VisitStartTime},{Atom[<<1>>],Atom[<<1>>]}][VisitStartTime]+Struct[{WEBCAM_TIME,VisitStartTime},{Atom[TimeObject],Atom[TimeObject]}][WEBCAM_TIME]]]
>   is not a valid Association or a list of rules. >>

and similarly for Values::invrl, even though "time" is handled correctly:

[image]

Finally, casting `TimeObject` to `AbsoluteTime` makes no diff either, eg:

```
Dataset[data][All, All, AbsoluteTime][All, 
 Association[#, "time" -> #["WEBCAM_TIME"] - #["VisitStartTime"]] &]
```

[image]

Gives a similar warning but refers to `Atom[Real]` and `Atom[Integer]` as per `AbsoluteTime`.

Is this another type inference fault?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug, although I cannot confirm if it is directly related to the named slot issues previously mentioned.

This is fixed in our latest internal development builds, though. I'll make sure we add this to our suite of tests for `Dataset`.

Comment: Stefan, was this bug introduced in 10.0.2?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just tried the use case in 10.0.1 and it worked.  So it appears to be a regression in 10.0.2.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, concur w/ WReach, worked in 10.0.1.

Comment: @Stefan, +1 for quick recognition of the issue. Will your dev team consider more thorough testing w/ `Dataset` because of its type system complications? `Titanic` and `Planets` are toy models.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes this appears to be a bug introduced in 10.0.2.

Comment: @alancalvitti yes we are concerned about the number of `Dataset` regressions in 10.0.2 and will be revising our testing of it in the future.

Comment: @alancalvitti this is fixed in 10.2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to related to the bug mentioned here: [Appending in Dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68979/appending-and-prepending-columns-to-a-dataset-in-10-0-2-0).

Up to a fix only a workaround might help