# 10.0.2 breaks a recursive "trie" query

Tags: bugs, dataset, associations, query

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.2**

---

The 10.0.2 `Dataset` type system complication breaks a recursive trie constructor that worked in 0.1:

```
byPrefix = Query[ 
   GroupBy[First],
   If[First@# == {}, First@Keys@#, byPrefix[#]] &,
   Rest];
```

Test on FDA NDC product dataset ~4k sorted nonproprietary drug names:

```
drugNames = {"levetiracetam", "prednisone", "lamotrigine", 
    "alprazolam", "amlodipine besylate", "amoxicillin", 
    "diltiazem hydrochloride", "bupropion hydrochloride", 
    "topiramate", "quetiapine fumarate", "carvedilol"} // 
   AssociationMap[{"SOS"}~Join~ Characters[#]~Join ~ {"EOF"} & ] // 
  Dataset
```

Then,

```
drugNames[byPrefix]
```

warns:

[image]

> ```
> Element with head Association is not of the form _String
> ```

but the normal form is OK:

```
drugNames[byPrefix] // Normal
```

[image]

It's not just a warning, it breaks lookup, even though note All `Keys` are `String`, not composite as implicated in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69098) 10.0.2 bug:

`drugNames[byPrefix]["SOS", Keys]` or `drugNames[byPrefix]["SOS", "p"]` raise msg:

> `Cannot take part ... of expression of the form _String`

while, again, with normal form workaround:

```
drugNames[byPrefix] // Normal // Dataset // Query["SOS", Keys]
```

> `{"l", "p", "a", "d", "b", "t", "q", "c"}`

The normal form of an expression should be the same as the normalizing twice. That's violated here.

**EDIT // Timing study**

Although this question is not about performance, adding a basic benchmark to address comments, which also reveals another consequence of this bug for `StringLength > 146`:

```
randomTestWord[len_] :=  
  RandomChoice[
    CharacterRange["a", "z"], {len}] // <|StringJoin[#] -> #|> &;
```

Using

```
randomWordData[len_, n_] := 
  Table[randomTestWord[len], {n}] // Association // Dataset;
```

test along two axes: by array length fixing `StringLength = 8`

```
words8Test = 
  Range[100, 1000, 100] // AssociationMap[ randomWordData[8, #] &] // 
   Dataset;
```

and by `StringLength` = {2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128} fixing array length = 100:

```
words100Test = 
  2^Range[7] // AssociationMap[makeDataset[#, 100] &] // Dataset;
```

Both look linear in input:

```
words8Test[All, First @ AbsoluteTiming @ byPrefix[#]&]  
words100Test[All, First @ AbsoluteTiming @ byPrefix[#]&]
```

[image]
[image]

BTW, another aspect of this bug:

```
randomTestWord[145] // Dataset // Query[byPrefix]  (* ok *)
```

But longer strings:

```
randomTestWord[146] // Dataset // Query[byPrefix] // Normal
```

> ```
> (* ... <|"m" -> <|"c" -> <|"j" -> <|"b" -> <|"h" -> <|"j" -> <|"b" -> <|"s" \
> -> <|"l" -> <|"r" -> <|"i" -> <|"x" -> <|"i" -> <|"k" -> <|"g" -> \
> <|"z" -> <|"u" -> 
>                     Dataset`Query`PackagePrivate`query[<|\
> "elhhqbrjgenygqvgmlnnksmttunqfwbsgfifnhmxhirrybnrziyzodaboabnycxhawjsf\
> ydvzrkfokuvekhoofakpatqijqvocuauicuvhgqoliqyhntxyyjuwitbhpdmcjbhjbslri\
> xikgzue" -> {"e"}|>]|>|> ... *)
> ```

Comment: Are you certain this worked properly in 10.0.1? It seems to just hang for me there.

Comment: @StefanR The code functions under 10.0.1 but it exhibits exponential time complexity with respect to string length.  If you trim the strings to (say) the first eight characters, then the code terminates in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @WReach, can you validate the exponential time complexity? That would not change from 10.0.1 to .2. Take a look at the timing studies I added, can you try larger parameters?

Comment: @StefanR, yes it worked in 10.0.1.

Comment: @alancalvitti I can confirm that the exponential time complexity occurs for the original code in 10.0.1 but not 10.0.2.  I ran it again just now.  `randomTestWord[145]` returns immediately on 10.0.2 but runs indefinitely in 10.0.1.  `randomTestWord[146]` runs indefinitely for me in both versions.  I can replicate your results for `words8Test` and `words100Test` in both versions.  I suppose that they dodge the exponential behaviour as they do not nest queries.  Note: I assumed that `makeDataset[#, 100]` in `words100Test` should actually be `randomWordData[100, #]`.

Answer (score 11):

There appears to be a bug in the type inference mechanism here. If you evaluate

```
<<Dataset`
<<TypeSystem`
```

and then

```
res = drugNames[byPrefix];
res // GetType

(* Assoc[Atom[String], Atom[String], AnyLength] *)
```

which is bogus. Basically that says it thinks the result is an `Association` with keys and values that are both `String`. We can compare this to the correct type:

```
Dataset[Normal[res]] // GetType

(*Assoc[Atom[String], 
 Assoc[Atom[String], 
  Assoc[Atom[String], 
   Assoc[Atom[String], 
    Assoc[Atom[String], 
     Assoc[Atom[String], 
      Assoc[Atom[String], 
       Assoc[Atom[String], 
        Assoc[Atom[String], 
         Assoc[Atom[String], 
          Assoc[Atom[String], Assoc[Atom[String], AnyType, 1], 1], 1],
          1], 1], 1], 1], 1], AnyLength], AnyLength], 8], 1] *)
```

Perhaps the type inference code isn't quite sure what to do with recursive functions like `byPrefix`.