# Handy / flexible directory tree operations

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, files-and-directories, gathering

Is there any shorter / more handy / more flexible way to get directory tree as a nested `Rules/Associations` list?

I tried to incorporate `FileNames` + `GatherBy` and `GroupBy`, but nothing was as short and handy as old fashioned:

```
ClearAll @ filesInDir;
filesInDir[dirname_, deep_] :=  If[
    DirectoryQ[dirname],
    FileBaseName[ dirname] -> (
          If[   deep == 1, 
                FileNameTake[#, -1], 
                filesInDir[#, deep - 1]
            ] & /@ FileNames["*", dirname]),
    FileNameTake[dirname, -1]
];


filesInDir[$UserBaseDirectory, 2]
```

> "Mathematica" -> {"ApplicationData" -> {"CCompilerDriver", 
>       "CloudObject", "CUDALink", "Parallel"}, 
>     "Applications" -> {...}, 
>     "Autoload" -> {...}, 
>     "FrontEnd" -> {"init.m"}, "Kernel" -> {"init.m"}, "Licensing" -> {},
>      "Paclets" -> {"Configuration", "Repository", "Temporary"}, 
>     "SystemFiles" -> {"CharacterEncodings", "FrontEnd", "Kernel", 
>       "SpellingDictionaries"}}

And now, from this nested rules **I want to go back** to the output of:

```
FileNameSplit /@ FileNames["*", $UserBaseDirectory, 2]
```

---

p.s.

I've chosen nested lists/associations to reduce `ByteCount` and make querying more user friendly. But if you can convince me I should keep a full paths list it would be a **valid answer too**.

Comment: Kuba, sorry about the broken answer.  I *will* try to fix it but I realize I am a bit tired to think clearly so it may not be today.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard no worries :)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the format that you want.  You have e.g. `"Licensing" -> {}` in your output list.  I assume this is OK (desired?) for directories but not files, correct?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep, since it is an empty directory. But At the end the exact format does not matter if I can convert between forms easily and detect what is a file.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The point is to have compact form of directory tree for user interface purposes and be able to convert it easily and use to create such directory tree in different directory for example. Or in general for functions like `FileDelete`, `CopyFile` etc.

Comment: I made one more attempt for today.  I doubt it is optimal even if it works; mostly I'd like to know if it *does* work and if the format is good for you.  I can attempt to refine it later.

Comment: If you want a simple `GroupBy`-based solution, try `GroupBy[DeleteCases[#, {}], First -> Rest, #0] &[FileNameSplit /@ FileNames[___, $UserBaseDirectory, 2]]`.  The only problem is that `FileNames` gives no indication as to what is a directory... (I'm pretty proud of finally finding a way to use `#0` though =P )

Comment: @2012rcampion nice, I had something similar, even with `#0` :) I don't remember why I left this way. I will accept and respond to answers when I will have more time to test their usage in real word cases (projects)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69942/10-0-2-breaks-a-recursive-trie-query

Comment: I notice this question doesn't have an Accepted answer.  I think you based on your comment above.

Answer (score 6):

First off, a more compact form of `filesInDir`:

```
fileTree[f_, d_] /; DirectoryQ[f] && d > 0 := 
 FileNameTake[f] -> (fileTree[#, d - 1] & /@ FileNames[___, f])
fileTree[f_, _] := FileNameTake[f]
```

Example usage:

```
fileTree[$UserBaseDirectory, 2]

(* "Mathematica" -> {"ApplicationData" -> {"CCompilerDriver", 
    "DeviceFramework", "ImageAcquisition", "Parallel"}, 
  "Applications" -> {}, "Autoload" -> {"PacletManager"}, 
  "FrontEnd" -> {"init.m"}, "Kernel" -> {"init.m"}, "Licensing" -> {},
   "Paclets" -> {"Configuration", "Repository", "Temporary"}, 
  "SystemFiles" -> {"CharacterEncodings", "FrontEnd", "Java", 
    "Kernel", "LibraryResources", "SpellingDictionaries"}} *)
```

Personally I don't like the way that bottom-level directories are treated the same way as files (head `String` instead of head `Rule`).  Here's an alternate method:

```
Clear[fileTree]

fileTree[f_, d_] /; DirectoryQ[f] := 
 FileNameTake[f] -> If[d > 0, fileTree[#, d-1]& /@ FileNames[___, f], Missing["TooDeep"]]
fileTree[f_, _] := FileNameTake[f]
```

Example usage:

```
fileTree[$UserBaseDirectory, 2]

(* "Mathematica" -> {"ApplicationData" -> {"CCompilerDriver" -> 
     Missing["TooDeep"], "DeviceFramework" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "ImageAcquisition" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "Parallel" -> Missing["TooDeep"]}, "Applications" -> {}, 
  "Autoload" -> {"PacletManager" -> Missing["TooDeep"]}, 
  "FrontEnd" -> {"init.m"}, "Kernel" -> {"init.m"}, "Licensing" -> {},
   "Paclets" -> {"Configuration" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "Repository" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "Temporary" -> Missing["TooDeep"]}, 
  "SystemFiles" -> {"CharacterEncodings" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "FrontEnd" -> Missing["TooDeep"], "Java" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "Kernel" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "LibraryResources" -> Missing["TooDeep"], 
    "SpellingDictionaries" -> Missing["TooDeep"]}} *)
```

You can replace `Missing["TooDeep"]` with whatever you want, as long as it's not a `List`.

---

To convert a tree (either form) to your list format:

```
treeToList[d_ -> _Missing] := {{d}}
treeToList[s_String] := {{s}}
treeToList[d_ -> l_] := Prepend[Prepend[d] /@ Join @@ (treeToList /@ l), {d}]
```

Example usage:

```
tree = fileTree[$UserBaseDirectory, 2];
treeToList[tree] // Column

(* {
 {"Mathematica"},
 {"Mathematica", "ApplicationData"},
 {"Mathematica", "ApplicationData", "CCompilerDriver"},
 {"Mathematica", "ApplicationData", "DeviceFramework"},
 {"Mathematica", "ApplicationData", "ImageAcquisition"},
 {"Mathematica", "ApplicationData", "Parallel"},
 {"Mathematica", "Applications"},
 {"Mathematica", "Autoload"},
 {"Mathematica", "Autoload", "PacletManager"},
 {"Mathematica", "FrontEnd"},
 {"Mathematica", "FrontEnd", "init.m"},
 {"Mathematica", "Kernel"},
 {"Mathematica", "Kernel", "init.m"},
 {"Mathematica", "Licensing"},
 {"Mathematica", "Paclets"},
 {"Mathematica", "Paclets", "Configuration"},
 {"Mathematica", "Paclets", "Repository"},
 {"Mathematica", "Paclets", "Temporary"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles", "CharacterEncodings"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles", "Java"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles", "Kernel"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles", "LibraryResources"},
 {"Mathematica", "SystemFiles", "SpellingDictionaries"}
} *)
```

We can't get back to the full output of `FileNameSplit /@ FileNames["*", $UserBaseDirectory, 2]` since the base path is lost when converting to a tree.

Answer (score 3):

Leonid Shifrin's [implementation of a trie](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/447/731) can be used for this purpose. It is available both for lists and for associations. For associations:

```
ClearAll[makeTreeAssoc];
makeTreeAssoc[wrds : {__String}] := Association@makeTreeAssoc[FileNameSplit /@ wrds];
makeTreeAssoc[wrds_ /; MemberQ[wrds, {}]] := makeTreeAssoc[DeleteCases[wrds, {}]];
makeTreeAssoc[wrds_] := Reap[If[# =!= {}, Sow[Rest[#], First@#]] & /@ wrds, _, #1 -> Association@makeTreeAssoc[#2] &][[2]]
```

Now you can do

```
tree[dir_] := makeTreeAssoc[FileNames["*", dir, 2]]
myTree = First@tree[$UserBaseDirectory]
```

Since the directory/file names are used as keys, I don't think there is a way to differentiate the files from the directories in the structure. You would have to check what it is upon retrieval.

OK so now we have to be able to go back to that other format too... I ended up with this

```
goBack[tree_, path_] := (
  Sow[path];
  If[Keys[tree] =!= {}, goBack[
      tree[#],
      Append[path, #]
      ] & /@ Keys[tree]]
  )

len = Length@FileNameSplit[$UserBaseDirectory];
Select[
 Reap[goBack[myTree, {}]][[2, 1]],
 Length[#] >= len &
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: much simpler now.  If this works right I think I would consider it superior.

Update 2: I attempted to add specific handling of files and directories.  Please tell me if this appears to work and produce a format that is acceptable to you.

```
fn[x : {___, {_, __}, ___}] := Normal @ GroupBy[x, First -> Rest, fn]
fn[x_List] := Join @@ x

files =
  Append[FileNameSplit@#, FileType@#] & /@
    FileNames["*", $UserBaseDirectory, 2];

DeleteCases[fn @ files, Directory -> {}, -3] /.
  {{Directory} -> {}, (x_ -> {File}) :> x}
```

Comment: @Kuba I just updated my code to be simpler but I think that problem remains.  I guess my file structure is different as I don't think I have files as keys in my test?  I'll try to fix that now.

Comment: @Kuba I just tried a different set of files and got errors, so I didn't test this well enough before posting.  Sorry.  I guess I'll delete this while I work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this recursive query which is linear-time in input (timing study [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69942/10-0-2-breaks-a-recursive-trie-query))

```
trie = Query[GroupBy@First, If[First@# == {}, {}, trie@#] &, Rest];
```

Variations on the above are possible and useful (see Antonov's Trie page [here](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/tries-with-frequencies-for-data-mining/) developed in 2013 but without Dataset).

Assume filenames have been split into path component lists, eg `"a/b/c"` --> `{"a","b","c"}` :

`flatFiles = FileNames["*.gsheet", "~/Google Drive/...", Infinity] // Dataset`

Then:

```
flatFiles[All, StringSplit[#, "/"] &][trie]
```