# How to "flatten" a nested Association?

Tags: associations

For example, I have a nested association like this

```
<|"fff" -> <|"2001" -> <|5040.` -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", 
       "S20010039", "S20010040", "S20010041", "S20010042"}|>, 
   "2005" -> <|4350.` -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"}, 
     3450.` -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>|>|>
```

I want to "Flatten" it like this

```
<|{fff, 2001, 5040.} -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", "S20010039", 
   "S20010040", "S20010041", "S20010042"}, {fff, 2005, 
   4350.} -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"}, {fff, 2005, 
   3450.} -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>
```

I can't figure out a good way. How to do it elegantly?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55745/121,
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83507/121,
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86578/121,
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107399/121

Comment: See also associationFlatten function described here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/837061?p_p_auth=QuUJXH8q

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry for late comment, these are so useful! Thank you so much!

Comment: @matheorem No problem!  I am glad you found them relevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another idea:

```
FixedPoint[Association[Normal[#] /. Rule[n_, m_Association] :>
               KeyMap[Append[n, #] &, m]] &, KeyMap[{#} &, asso]]
```

> ```
> <|{"fff", "2001", 5040.} -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", "S20010039",
>    "S20010040", "S20010041", "S20010042"}, {"fff", "2005", 
>    4350.} -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"}, {"fff", "2005", 
>    3450.} -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>
> ```

Which is the same as:

```
Association[Normal[KeyMap[List, asso]] //.
 (n_ -> m_Association) :> Normal[KeyMap[Append[n, #] &, m]]]
```

Comment: Nice use of `FixedPoint`. (+1)

Comment: Clever!! +1 : )

Answer (score 8):

I think this works:

```
fn[a_ -> _[b__Rule]]  := Flatten[{a, #}] -> #2 & @@@ {b}
fn[x : (_ -> _fn) ..] := Flatten[fn /@ {x}]
fn[a_Association]     := <|a /. Association -> fn|>
```

Test:

```
fn[input]   (* input being your input expression *)
```

> ```
> <|{"fff", "2001", 5040.} -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", "S20010039", "S20010040", 
>    "S20010041", "S20010042"},
>   {"fff", "2005", 4350.} -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"},
>   {"fff", "2005", 3450.} -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>
> ```

Perhaps cleaner:

```
ClearAll[fn]

a_ -> fn[b__] ^:= Flatten[{a, #}] -> #2 & @@@ Flatten[{b}]
fn[a_Association] := a /. Association -> fn
fn[x_List] := <|x|>
```

I feel as though there should be a simpler form than this but it eludes me at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

```
asso = <|"fff" -> <|
    "2001" -> <|
      5040.` -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", "S20010039", "S20010040", 
        "S20010041", "S20010042"}|>, 
    "2005" -> <|4350.` -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"}, 
      3450.` -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>|>|>
```

Ugly but working:

```
flatten = Association @* Flatten @* KeyValueMap[
   If[ MatchQ[#2, _Association], 
       flatten @ KeyMap[
          Function[key, If[MatchQ[#, {_, __}], Append[#, key], {#, key}]], 
          #2
       ], 
       # -> #2
   ] &
]
```

```
f @ asso
```

> ```
> <|
>  {"fff", "2001", 5040.} -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", "S20010039",    "S20010040", "S20010041", "S20010042"}, 
>  {"fff", "2005", 4350.} -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"}, 
>  {"fff", "2005",3450.} -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}
> |>
> ```

Comment: Sorry for late comment. It is Working! Thank you! But for me, Coolwater's answer is easier to understand ; )

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a different way using the experimental (as of 13.1) `Tree` structure and related functions. This replaces the somewhat tricky `FixedPoint` or `ReplaceRepeated` constructions with an entirely new form of awkwardness.

First, let's name our nested association:

```
assoc = 
  <|"fff" -> <|
    "2001" -> <|5040.` -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", 
       "S20010039", "S20010040", "S20010041", "S20010042"}|>, 
    "2005" -> <|4350.` -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"}, 
      3450.` -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>|>|>;
```

Then we can turn it into a `Tree` object, though it requires a [surprising and quasi-documented circumlocution](https://wolfram.com/xid/0b8c9p7izw-ga0fnf):

```
tree = ExpressionTree[assoc, "Association"];
```

From there we can find the "position" of each leaf, meaning the association keys needed to reach it:

```
pos = TreePosition[tree, _, "Leaves"]
(*
{{Key[fff],Key[2001],Key[5040.]},
 {Key[fff],Key[2005],Key[4350.]},
 {Key[fff],Key[2005],Key[3450.]}} 
*)
```

I think we need the `Key` wrappers for our next step, so we'll get rid of them at the end:

```
KeyMap[ReplaceAll[Key->Identity],
  AssociationMap[
    TreeExtract[tree,#,TreeData]&,
    pos]]
(*
<|
  {fff,2001,5040.}->{S20010037,S20010038,S20010039,S20010040,S20010041,S20010042}, 
  {fff,2005,4350.}->{S20050448,S20050449}, 
  {fff,2005,3450.}->{S20050998,S20050999}
|> 
*)
```

Comment: very interesting!  once we have `pos` we can use it with `Extract` or `Part`  directly on `assoc`.  E.g., `AssociationThread[pos /. Key -> Identity, assoc[[##]] & @@@ pos]` or `AssociationThread[pos /. Key -> Identity, Extract[assoc, pos]]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the new solution : ) But I have to point out that this is not as efficient as `FixedPoint` solution.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on Pillsy's approach using [`TreeGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeGraph.html) + [`ExpressionTree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpressionTree.html):

Interestingly, sink vertices of `TreeGraph` + `ExpressionTree` combination contains all the information we need (values and the key-path traversed to reach each value).

```
tg = TreeGraph[ExpressionTree[assoc, "Association"],
  VertexLabels -> Automatic, VertexLabelStyle -> 14,
  GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left}]
```

[image]

So we extract and process the leaves to get the desired association:

```
leaves = GeneralUtilities`GraphSinks @ tg;

AssociationThread @@ Reverse[Transpose@leaves /. Key -> Identity]
```

> ```
> <|{"fff", "2001", 5040.} -> {"S20010037", "S20010038", "S20010039", 
>   "S20010040", "S20010041", "S20010042"}, 
> {"fff", "2005", 4350.} -> {"S20050448", "S20050449"},   
> {"fff", "2005", 3450.} -> {"S20050998", "S20050999"}|>
> ```